CSI Camera Module and Libcamera Issues on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I am facing various issues while trying to use a CSI camera module on my Raspberry Pi device with Ubuntu 24.04.
System information:

Device: Raspberry Pi 5
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04
Camera Module: Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3 (IMX708)
Connection Type: CSI (Camera Serial Interface)

I'm unable to view the camera feed.
I installed libcamera and related tools using the following commands:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libcamera0.2 libcamera-tools libcamera-v4l2

The installation completed without any errors.
To load the necessary kernel module, I used the following command:
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2

This step also completed without any errors.
I ran the following command to check if the camera was detected:
v4l2-ctl --list-devices

The command correctly lists the connected camera.
When I attempt to get the camera feed using the libcamera-hello command, the camera initializes but no image is displayed. Sometimes I encounter a QSocketNotifier error, which resolves when I change the QT version, but the camera feed is still unavailable.
I Have tried editing /boot/config.txt. I added the following lines to the config.txt file:
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
camera_auto_detect=1
dtoverlay=imx708, cam0
dtoverlay=imx708, cam1
gpu_mem=512
start_x=1

After making these changes and restarting the system, the issue persists.
I added my user to the video group using sudo usermod -aG video $USER. This did not resolve the issue either.
Additional information:

The dmesg logs do not show any errors related to the camera.
The camera module works flawlessly on Raspberry Pi OS.
About three weeks ago, I managed to get the camera working on a similar system configuration, however after reinstalling the system, I followed the same steps but could not achieve the same result.
I tried using the raspi-config tool to configure the camera, but after making changes and rebooting, the system only boots into the terminal screen without a graphical interface.


@sleepyhead please help

The Pi 5 doesn't have a bcm2835 chip.  It uses a 2711. Unfortunately, this makes most csi cameras incompatible if running v4l2 which expects unicam.
I don't think there is a workaround for Ubuntu/ROS on a Pi 5.  Pi 4s work OK.
I have also tried a USB camera, though it found it in lsusb, it wan't detected in v4l2-ctl.  I suspect that this is mostly a hardware issue on the PI 5, and since this is an i/o chip,it might effect SPI, GPIO, etc.

Yes, I tried on Canonical Ubuntu 24.04 its available Camera and Cheese Apps, which disappointingly do not work with Raspberry Pi V2 Camera on a Raspberry Pi 5. My post: Do Ubuntu 24.04 Raspberry Pi Desktop Camera and Cheese apps support Raspberry Pi Camera v2 or v3? . Its unfortunate that Canonical does not give support for the Raspberry Pi Camera even though the Raspberry Pi 5 itself is supported. A USB Webcam along with the Raspberry Pi CSI Camera also is not supported with the "Camera App. Hopefully appropriate Camera support will be developed.
